# hard drive problem

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I have a problem with my laptop that I am unable to solve.
I bought this Lenovo E495 Laptop with two hard drives:

1 SSD with windows preinstalled
1 HD

I installed Ubuntu after a while, with automatic partitioning and it had been installed on the 2nd HD, which is a lot slower.

So I tried partitioning the SSD to install it alongside Windows... and I messed up.
It wouldn't boot anymore from anything, I tried to follow guides to fix the bootloader but messed even more I guess :)
I ended up reinstalling windows from recovery disk.

But. It has been installed on the 2nd slow HD.
The SSD is not recognized at all.
It's not visibile in the disk management, it's not visible from ubuntu live USB, it's not visible in the BIOS, it's not visible in the diagnostic tool from lenovo.

The only strange thing is if I press F12, I see which options are available for booting.
I see windows, I see USB and then I see something called Ubuntu. Which I believe was my test when I messed up? I have no idea if it's the SSD or just an entry somewhere I did by mistake.

I am not sure if the situation is clear.
Is it a hardware fault?
It would be strange because the laptop is new, it was working perfectly until I started installing and uninstalling stuff.
If not, is there any kind of advanced tool I could use to check? From the Live Ubuntu I tried checking hardware using command line tools but no trace of the SSD.

Any input appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this a new under-warranty laptop? Sounds like a hardware problem. I'd contact the seller or manufacturer.

Comment: yep I already contacted them and waiting for an answer. I suspect it's hardware issue, just so weird it has happened while messing up installing stuff. But yeah.. thank you!